# In a step by step way how do I build this open source flex project in flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

in a step by step way, how do I build the products in this open source flex project?
i have flex builder 3 and a mac with java so I should be able to build this.

There is a library and an example project called simpleworld.

[http://code.google.com/p/moccasin/](http://code.google.com/p/moccasin/downloads/list)

I want to build the latest version: 0.24

There is no readme so when I open flex builder, I don't know what to do next.

Bonus round: how do I build with Ant?

Answer (score 0):

1) Unzip downloaded files

2) Open Flex and right click your Project and go to 'Properties'.

3) Click 'Flex Build Path'

4) Click 'Library Path' tab

5) Click 'Add SWC...'

6) Click 'Browse' to navigate to your unzipped files and select moccasin-core/bin/moccasin-core.swc

7) Those files are now imported into your project. Whenever you find a library just look for the .swc file in the bin folder and add it you your build paths.

Comment: I want to build the simpleworld project in that distribution as well. I don't have an existing project yet.

Comment: 1) Create a new Flex Project and point the file path at the unzipped moccasin-0.24/simpleworld-flex folder. 

2)Click Next until you get to the screen to set the build paths and import the SWC. 

3) Click Finish to create the project, which will initially error out. 

4) Copy the com folder from moccasin-0.24/simpleworld/src to moccasin-0.24/simpleworld-flex/src and you will be able to compile and run simpleworld-flex